# Is racism absent in jinnkind?

Tags: jinn, creation

Just before creation of prophet Adam. Allah sent an angel to collect mud from different parts of earth, hence we have people with different skin colors. The weak among mankind became racists.

Since jinn are created from smokeless fire can it be construed that racism is absent in jinnkind?

Also Allah doesn't describe hur al ayn as fair complexioned, He says they are beautiful thereby negating the "superiority" of fair complexion or light skin.

Comment: "Should I prostrate to one You created from clay?" still sounds pretty racist to me...

Comment: I meant racism among their kind..

Answer (score -1):

How could there be "racism" in jinnkind when "race" as a "categorizing term referring to human beings was first used in the English language in the late 16th century. Until the 18th century it had a generalized meaning similar to other classifying terms such as type, sort, or kind. Occasional literature of Shakespeare’s time referred to a “race of saints” or “a race of bishops.” By the 18th century, race was widely used for sorting and ranking the peoples in the English colonies—Europeans who saw themselves as free people, Amerindians who had been conquered, and Africans who were being brought in as slave labour—and this usage continues today."?

Comment: The term didnt exist, but it existed in other forms like twelver shia hating zunj.